# How-to open and close files in a loop

Tags: c, file, file-io, file-descriptor

I have a `while` loop that opens (and closes) files in each loop. After some loops I end up in the "Too many open files" problem – but I call `close` each time after reading the file's content. Could anyone assist me with this?

```
for (;;)
{
    dir = opendir( "/proc");

    while ( (entry = readdir( dir)) != NULL)
    {
        pid = atoi( entry->d_name);

        // Only processes with a "number" are of interest
        if ( pid == 0)
            continue;

        sprintf( fname, "/proc/%d/cmdline", pid);

        fd = open( fname, O_RDONLY);
        read( fd, line, MAX_LINE);

        /* ... */

        close( fd);
    }
}
```

Comment: write close(fd) out of while loop .

Comment: Is there a way to reset the index of the opened directory to reset the readdir method? I re-open the dir every time to iterate from the beginning

Comment: @anon `close(fd)` should remain in the `while` loop because the `open` is within the `while` loop.

Comment: @Greeny you can reset your read of an open directory with `rewinddir`. However, if you think new files may have been created my preference would be to `closedir` and reopen. `rewinddir` will certainly miss some things (for instance a rename of the directory and a creation of a new directory in its place). If you want to use `readdir` across changes to that directory, I suggest you carefully read http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readdir_r.html - it's unspecified behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are doing an `opendir` in the loop, but never doing a `closedir`. That will leak an fd on each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: +1: Spot on.  There's also no error checking in the code, but there should be.

Comment: Yes, I omitted the error checking to reduce the noise. But thanks for the hint :)